Data Ingestion Is Slow in MemgraphLab from Kafka
I am using Memgraph Lab with Docker on a EC2 instance. I am ingesting data from Kafka. I have realised that the lag is very high.I want to decrease it as much as possible.
I tried to run the below code: -
STORAGE MODE IN_MEMORY_ANALYTICAL;
But it resulted in the Memgraph lab getting disconnected every single time. Is there a way to speed up the process? Any inputs would help.

Did you create appropriate indexes in Memgraph? When saying that the lag is very high, what exactly are you referring to? Can you add more information to that or steps to reproduce? I would suggest following the best practices on indexing so you make sure they are being utilized properly.
